# Personalizar input de tipo time simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Necesito que tenga este rango:  8:00AM - 8:00PM

```
= f.input :start , :ampm => true, :minute_step => 60, :prompt => { :Hora => "Hour", :minutos => false }, :required => false
```

Answer (score 1):

Por defecto simple_form no dispone de la opción que requieres, sin embargo podrías crear un custom input en el que determines el rango de las horas:

```
# app/inputs/hour_input.rb
class HourInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
  def input(wrapper_options = nil)
    merged_input_options = merge_wrapper_options(input_html_options, wrapper_options)

    input_options[:selected] = selected_value
    @builder.select(attribute_name, hour_options, input_options, merged_input_options)
  end

  private

  def hour_options
    hour = [['Selecione hora', '00:00:00']]
    (8..20).each do |h|
      hour << ["#{h}:00", format('%02d:00:00', h)]
    end
    hour
  end

  def selected_value
    value = object.send(attribute_name)
    value && value.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
  end
end
```

Y luego llamar desde la vista con `= f.input :start , as: :hour`